How do I send a scheduled message to a chat using a telegram bot?
I am writing my telegram bot and I ran into a problem. I need the bot to send a message not to the chat, but to its "Scheduled messages" of this chat.
In the telegram client, I can do this, and the documentation for implementing my client with this function is also described:
https://core.telegram.org/api/scheduled-messages
But if we are talking about Bot API, I saw that the bot does not have any fields in the SendMessage method to indicate that the message has been postponed:
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage
The question is, am I missing something? Maybe there is still a way to get the bot to send messages to "Scheduled messages"? I know about the ways to use additional libraries, but this is not exactly what I need. I will be very grateful for any advice!

Actually, this is actually intended behavior of the Bot API. Bot's cannot schedule messages in chats. Scheduling of messages is only possible in the Telegram API (MTProto) which can be used to build Telegram client apps/user bots.
In another thought, there's no point in sending a message as scheduled message using a normal Telegram Bot. You can programmatically set the date and time to call the sendMessage and also bots are not real users, hence they don't have the scheduled message section as well.
Hope this clarifies.
